# cannot convert auth token to string

Tags: javascript, authorization, token, fetch-api

I need to request `POST` method to authorize and set current location of  user in my react-native application. As `authorization` header,I add `token` which I get before from API and saved it to the state. However, when I make request, I get error message of `auth header empty`. Whereas, when I `console.log` the token, it prints correctly. I guess the issue is something about the type of token. I tried to convert it to string, but nothing changed.

By the way, I checked request with static token - copy&pasted token instead of `this.state.token` and it worked perfectly, so it is clear that I live problem with converting the token.

Here is the code that I make request.

```
console.log("AUTH TOKEN: ", this.state.token);
        var Url = "https://-----------";
        return fetch(Url, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.state.token
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({'latitude': this.state.location.coords.latitude.toString(), 'longitude': this.state.location.coords.longitude.toString()})
        })
        // .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
            })
            .done();
```

here is the result of request on console.

[image]

Has anyone lived such issue before?

Comment: Could you print the request? maybe you're sending something wrong.

Comment: That response may not be the response for the POST from your code but instead the response from the CORS preflight OPTIONS request the browser automatically sends on its own. But the browser doesn’t send the Authorization header as part of that OPTIONS request—so if the server you’re sending that request to requires the Authorization header even for OPTIONS requests, then the preflight fails and browser never moves on to trying the POST request from your code. So if you control the server you’re sending the request it, you need to configure it to not require authorization for OPTIONS requests.

Comment: @sideshowbarker but what if I have not control on the server? Cannot I fix the issue from client side?

Comment: If the server you’re sending the request to requires authorization for OPTIONS requests, there’s nothing you can do to fix it in a way that would allow you to make cross-origin requests to it directly from frontend JavaScript code running in a Web browser. Your options are to set up some kind of trusted proxy that you can control, and route the request from your frontend JavaScript code through that proxy — or else just make the request completely from your backend code rather than your frontend code.

Comment: @sideshowbarker I got i, but is it normal that I get success when I check request through postman?

Comment: Because Postman isn’t a Web application that’s bound by the same-origin policy the way your frontend JavaScript code is for security reasons. Instead Postman is a browser extension, and browser extensions can basically do anything they want without normal security restrictions.